# Does "Last Painted Hero" time have an impact on SEO and search engine rankings?

Tags: seo, performance, ranking, render

Does "Last Painted Hero" (LPH) time have an impact on SEO and search engine rankings?

For instance, a 3rd party vendor decreased our LPH time from [16.200s](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/191101_3V_7cae61ff0d5b9d0afed366d1a9fdcbbd/) to [1.200s](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/191111_2S_5177959f4291695d7aef6548d1d28454/).

We're running a separate SEO campaign at the same so it is hard to measure impact the vendor's work had on our SERP position.

Comment: I'd never heard of "Last Painted Hero."  It is a [performance metric that SpeedCurve made up](https://speedcurve.com/blog/last-painted-hero/): "a synthetic metric that shows you when the last piece of critical content is painted."

Comment: ***...so it is hard to measure impact the vendor's work had on our SERP position.*** This could take many months.